# mongo $in query isn't working with sails.js find method

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

var arr=[18,5,6,....];
Beneficiary.find({Ward: { $in: arr } }).done(function(err,ben) {
              if(err)
                  console.log(err);
              else
              {
                console.log(ben);
              }
          });

I want to fetch those records from Beneficiary collection where Ward are from arr list. This code gives no error but returns blank array []. Although data is there in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$in` keyword only if you are playing with `Collection.native(...)`. Since you are not, use:

`Beneficiary.find({
  Ward: arr
});`

As you can see in [docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md#in-pairs).

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use array in `IN` operator you can use like this :

```
Beneficiary.find({Ward: { $in: [arr[0],arr[1]] } })
```